# Am I supposed to use Webpack with the Angular project I am trying to port from React?

Tags: angular, webpack

I made a tiny [Logo clone](https://github.com/mrakgr/Logo-Clone-In-React) in React that uses Vite for its build system, and I want to port it to Angular. Trying to import `monaco-editor` gives me the following kinds of errors.

```
./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/severityIcon/browser/media/severityIcon.css:6:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

There are instructions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-esm.md) on how to set up Webpack for it. I could do it for a non-Angular project without problem, but with Angular I am confused what its relationship to Webpack is. It has its own build tools, and it doesn't have the `webpack.config.js` file. Are those using Webpack under the hood?

If they aren't, am I supposed to ignore the Angular CLI tool, and bring in Webpack or Vite on my own initiative here? Or is there a way to configure its existing build system in order to import the package properly?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXxLDiqBymw

Comment: This Youtube video explains it to me, I'll try following the instructions.

Comment: Basically, what I need to do is import: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack and replace the existing build and serve commands in the angular.json file.